# Delphi to C# through (unregistered) COM interoperability example?

Tags: c#, delphi, com, interop

I'm trying to build a little working example of a COM class written in Delphi that exposes a simple "sum" function that is used by a C# client.

Firstly I'm trying to set up a registered COM version.
After that I'll go for the unregistered version.

I have written the little mock function in a Delphi DLL project:

```
function SumIntegers(const _a, _b: integer): integer;
begin
   Result := _a + _b;
end;
```

But after some hours spent searching I didn't find any tutorial or info about consuming a Delphi DLL in C# through COM. (or links are outdated/unavailable)

Does anyone have suggestions or can help me with this mock?
Since I'm quite new to Delphi I could have made some mistakes: please forgive me for any of them.
Any kind of help will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Can't you just build a regular DLL? Why do you need COM?

Comment: That's because i need to use some Delphi functions of an old program on my new c# program and I'm exploring some methods to do it (without involving the registry).

Comment: A regular DLL is the easiest way to achieve that. You don't need COM.

Comment: _"i need to use some Delphi functions of an old program"_ - and porting those to C# is not an option?

Comment: The Delphi code in your question isn't COM. Are you sure that COM is what you need? Why not p/invoke?

Comment: About how much "effort" are we talking? Are thise "some Delphi functions" actually many, many functions? Is it highly complex? Does it depend on other libraries you have no code of ... ? What I am after is: as already written above, my first thought would be to either find a suitable dotnet alternative that does the same thing or port the delphi code myself. I'd only go for p/invoke or even COM solutions if that's actually less effort than the first 2 options. And I take maintainance into account.

Comment: i know, but using a regular dll implies a lot of refactoring work in the old program. I konw that is the easyest way but i also wanted to know an example with COM Delphi->C# which also is quite impossible to find on the internet (so potentially useful for other people :) )

Comment: And how would COM require less refactoring?

Comment: sadly we are talking of an Highly complex program. It's actually written in Delphi and C++ and COM is a possibile temporary solution to use some of the older parts, while refactoring them to C#.

Comment: I don't know how, it's just an option since the older program uses COM too, i'm just searching on how to do it, once i'll be able to set up an example i'll make my own calculations on which is the easiest method to achieve my arrangement.

Comment: *"an example with COM Delphi->C#"* The fact that the client is written in C# is irrelevant. COM is language-agnostic. Any documentation about writing a COM server in Delphi will help (and I doubt it is "quite impossible to find on the internet").

Comment: Ok, i know that is irrelevant, i only written it to simplify search by other users with the same problem. 
Sadly is not as easy as you said to find tutorials on the internet. By the way i can "self"-reply to anyone that could have the same problem: you have to use an ActiveX project to setup a COM server in Delphi. 
[link](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+II+Delphi+Object-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+12+From+COM+to+COM/A+First+COM+Server/) This could help. 
Thank you anyway for the suggestions.

Comment: @thetimevoyager Some decent tutorials about developing COM clients/servers in Delphi (and C++Builder) are at http://techvanguards.com/com/ Then you should read Microsoft's documentation on consuming COM objects in C#, ie: [Exposing COM Components to the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/exposing-com-components)

Comment: This question isn't really useful. Apparently you already have a COM server and you want to consume it from C#. A very comprehensively documented topic. And yet the question offers some non COM Delphi code.

Comment: It makes more sense to deploy the COM object in C# and use the object in Delphi. This way you don't come into conflict with the garbage collector. I myself work with non registered C#-COM objects in Delphi.  I now have a C # PropertyReader / Property Writer as a COM object with which I can execute normal C # objects in Delphi without a COM signature. Unfortunately, the topic is too complex to be able to post in one post.

Comment: @thetimevoyager I should work on the sequel. https://github.com/sauter-direkt/Delphi-CSharp